# How can i import d3plus in angular-cli project

Tags: angular-cli, d3plus

Hi I'm using d3 to make chart in angular-cli project
I have imported d3 in my component as

```
import * as d3 from 'd3'
```

Now I want to import d3plus to wrap text.
I installed d3plus using `npm i d3plus --save`

inside my angular-cli file I add d3plus.js under script tag

Then I'm trying to import d3plus as

```
import * as d3plus from d3plus
```

but I get an error

```
/~/d3plus/src/init.coffe Module parse faild unxpect charater #
```

Comment: I'm in the same boat and haven't been able to find anything about it...